# ngAfterViewInit of Parent Vs ngAfterViewInit of child

Tags: angular

Will ngAfterViewInit of Parent always run after the ngAfterViewInit of child ?

```
<Parent>
 <child></child>
<Parent>
```

From parent's ngAfterViewInit I am emitting some data to child .
In Child's  ngAfterViewInit I am subscribing to the the data. But the subscription is not
triggered. Child in my case is a grid which has heavy api calls in ngOnInit. When I consoled logged I found out Child's ngAfterViewInit is
running after the parent's ngAfterViewInit. So when I emit payload from
Parent's ngAfterViewInit the subscribers in Child are not configured as
its ngAfterViewInit ran after I emitted the payload from the parent.

Comment: why you are subscribing the data into ngAfterViewInit in child component instead of constructor?, and also in other way you can create instance of child component in parent component and do call method of child component.

Comment: There is DOM manipulation which needs to be done on the basis on input from parentEmitter. Those DOM elements will only be available in ngAfterViewInit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `ngAfterViewInit` of the parent component will always run after the child.

In the angular docs that you can find [here](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-event-sequence) about `ngAfterViewInit` is said that :

> Respond after Angular initializes the component's views and child views, or the view that contains the directive.

So if we trust the docs the first `ngAfterViewInit` will be always called from the "most-nested" visible component part of the view.

If you don't trust the docs :D here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngafterviewinit-order-example?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcmp2%2Fcmp2.component.html) open the console and observe.

About passing data between components, you can always pass the data trough the `@Input` and things will most likely work.

### Edit

I saw the additional info in your comment, another way in which you can interact with your child component from the parent is by using `@ViewChild`, if you target the child component with `@ViewChild` you can invoke whatever method you need from the child inside the parent's `ngAfterViewInit`